# Regex to strip text after comment char

Tags: regex

I know the short answer to this question is to 'use a parser', but I'm curious if this simple rule can be implemented with a regex only. I want to remove comments from a line, where a comment is a `;` and everything after that until a newline. For example:

```
1+2+3 ; this is my comment
2+3
```

The regex I can use for this is:

```
>>> re.sub(r";.+", " ", s).split()
['1+2+3', '2+3']
```

Now I would like to introduce a string, which is something between double-quotes, such as `"this is a string"`, which also recognizes an escape character within it, such as `"this is a \";string;\""`, which would be interpreted as: `this is a ";string;"`.

Is it possible to remove comments via a regex with the string type as well? Here would be a few example inputs:

```
1+2+3 ; this is my comment
1+2+"h;\";;;\"ello;" ; another comment
1+2+;"a comment ;;;
1+2+ "; \"" ";\"hello" ; comment
```

And to match a single string: `"[^\\"]*(?:\\.[^\\"]*)*"`. Here is a regex101 with both a string-only and a comment-only regex with some example patterns: https://regex101.com/r/3WTWtY/1.

Comment: Regex is like any other parser needs to know what kind of tokens to match at the start so as to keep them. If your operands can be matched with `(?:\d+(?:\.\d+)?|"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^\\"]*)*")`, and the operators are `+` or whitespace, you might use something like `^((?:\d+(?:\.\d+)?|"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^\\"]*)*")(?:\s*[+\s]\s*(?:\d+(?:\.\d+)?|"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^\\"]*)*")?)*)\s*;.*` and replace with `$1` or `\1`. See https://regex101.com/r/Ju4tMG/1/. Well, I do not quite get the 3rd line, I made the second and each subsequent operand pattern optional.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew wow that is a pretty hairy regex! Very neat, thanks for the link too. For the above problem, would a regex be used? Or that would be considered too tricky/unmaintainable and a parser would be used.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew btw, when I was typing this question up I was thinking "well, I hope Wiktor is still awake..."

Comment: I am not sure what your requirements are. It may turn out a parser is really the best choice if you cannot describe the starting parsing point other than start of string. If you can assume any code line is always a single line, it can be done with regex, but again, you need to know what the token patterns are. Besides, this ``1+2+()*&^"*;;;"h;\";;;\"ello;" ; another comment`` example is too "weird".

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew how does the other answer look on the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try matching up to the first `;` in the line which is not enclosed in double quotes and then discarding everything after and including that `;`. To do that you can use this regex:

```regex
^(([^;"]|("(?:\\.|[^\\"])*"))*);.*$
```

which matches some number (0 or more) of either:

- `[^;"]`: a character which is not a `;` or `"`; or
- `"(?:\\.|[^\\"])*"`: a quoted string which includes some number of either an escaped character (`\\.`) or a character which is not a backslash or quote (`[^\\"]`)

followed by a semicolon (`;`) and some number of characters (`.*`) until end of string (`$`). The portion prior to the semicolon is captured in group 1.

If there is a match, the entire string is replaced with group 1 (`\1`), resulting in the comment being removed.

In python:

```py
import re

strs = [
        r'a "str\"ing" ; and a comment',
        r'1+2+3 ; this is my comment',
        r'1+2+"h;\";;;\"ello;" ; another comment',
        r'1+2+;"a comment ;;;',
        r'1+2+ "; \"" ";\"hello" ; comment',
        r'(*1+2+"hello")+3 ; this is my comment',
        r'1+2+()*&^"*;;;"h;\";;;\"ello;" ; another comment',
        r'1 ; comment with "string\" including ; "'
        ]

for s in strs:
    res = re.sub(r'^(([^;"]|("(?:\\.|[^\\"])*"))*);.*$', r'\1', s)
    print(res)
```

Output:

```
a "str\"ing" 
1+2+3 
1+2+"h;\";;;\"ello;" 
1+2+
1+2+ "; \"" ";\"hello" 
(*1+2+"hello")+3 
1+2+()*&^"*;;;"h
1
```

Comment: cool, thanks for this, but the second-to-last one I think is mis-identifying the character.

Comment: @David542 yes, it just occurred to me too, it's because it was a greedy match. I've corrected the regex

Comment: very cool, thanks. Could you please just briefly comment the regex to show what it's doing and I'll accept it? Thanks for your help. For example, why you decided to use a re-replace with the ``\1`` etc.

Comment: @David542 I've updated with an explanation of how the regex and code works. Let me know if you need any more.